# asp.net live countdown timers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page that dynamically creates multiple asp:labels with that have timer values such as:

```
    1d 12h 34m 35s
    2d 2h 3m 39s
    10d 23h 12m 9s
```

Those values get refreshed every 5 minutes.

What I would like to do is have them live counting down until the page refreshes.
I would suspect that javascript would be the best way but not sure how to even begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try `triggers` of `AJAX`

There's a [walkthrough on the Timer control available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I just need to be able to see the labels counting down without postback to the server.

Comment: I know what you are looking for. You need a client side `timer` which can change the label value without refreshing the whole page. AJAX update panel and triggers is the way to do this. Have a look at the given link, you will get my point.

Comment: I am already using that to refresh the data every 5 minutes but I don't want to do it every 1 second. If you get my meaning. Means I am polling the server every 1 second which is not good. It I can leave the countdown up to the client it would be better.

Comment: You need a client side timer which can change the label's value without refreshing the whole page. Right? So you need to implement a separate `timer` from that one you already have. Is it really difficult to make some one get your point by chatting :) You must try it

Comment: will give it shot and report back

Comment: The Timer control keeps posting back on every tick.